# Testing redux-form with enzyme using general function

Tags: redux-form, enzyme

So i'm trying to write a test to my component while using redux-form and enzyme.
So far, for my simple components i've created the following function

```js
export const mountWithContext = (node, store) => {
  const nodeToMount = store ? <Provider store={store} >{node}</Provider> : node;
  return mount(nodeToMount);
};
```

The issue is that when i'm trying to use react-redux as well it fails.
Trying to do:

```js
class Form extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div><TestComponent /></div>
  }
}

const TestForm = reduxForm({ form: 'testForm' })(Form);
const enzymeWrapper = mountWithContext(TestForm, store)
```

And i'm getting the following error

```js
'Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `function` supplied to `Provider`, expected a single ReactElement.
Invariant Violation: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.
```

Any idea why this happens and how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is 6 months old. For others who run into similar error messages:

The rendering of `<Provider>{ node }</Provider>` should actually be `<Provider><Node /></Provider>` or something similar. The error is basically saying that it requires an element and the children used as `{ node }` instead of `<Node/>` is a function.

```
export const mountWithContext = (Node, store) => {
  const nodeToMount = store ? (
    <Provider store={store} >
      <Node />
    </Provider>
  ) : <Node />;
  return mount(nodeToMount);
};
```

So just change the argument name of `node` to `Node` and usage in JSX from `{node}` to `<Node />` or `<Node></Node>`